# How to use grep with fread in Rstudio?

Tags: r, grep, fread

I have a large csv file that I want to import into Rstudio. Because it is so big (~29GB), I would like to only import specific rows at a time, rather than import the whole thing and then filter. I have been trying to use `grep` in the `cmd =`  argument in `fread()`, however, I keep getting the message that

`'grep' is not a recognized internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.`

I have installed http://cygwin.com, and have even tried manually adding the path (C:\cygwin64\bin) to the Windows environment, but still, I keep getting the error message.

As such, I suppose I have two questions:

1. How do I get grep to work when using fread to import a CSV into Rstudio?
2. Once grep is working, what syntax would I use to only import rows that contain a certain string?

```
library(rgbif)
library(data.table)

#Download the csv (note: downloads a zip file ~7GB, unzipped ~29GB
occ_download_get("0299151-200613084148143") #add argument, path = ,if you want to direct the download

#I now only want to import the rows that contain "Acanthiza pusilla", for example.
fread() # it's here that I am unsure of the correct syntax
```

Any help would be appreciated. Additionally, let me know if you require more information.
Thanks

Comment: Did you restart R after you changed your path? In R, does `Sys.which("grep")` return the correct path. Please show exactly what your `fread()` code looked like to make it clear what you tried.

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick. I did indeed forget to restart R after adding the path. I have since figured out how to use the grep within fread. The answer from @foreach also helped. I ended up with the following which works `fread(cmd = paste("grep", "Acanthiza.pusilla", filename))`

Answer (score 1):

```
fread(cmd='findstr /r Acanthiza.pusilla [your file location]"')
ex) fread(cmd='findstr /r Acanthiza.pusilla \"C:\\Users\\abc\\Documents\\test.csv\"')
```